# C++ Phone Number Program

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am new to this forum and am looking for some assistance, any help would be greatly appreciated! I am stuck on this assignment for my programming fundamentals 1 class and am desperate at this point as I have been stuck for hours on end. Thank you.

Here is the prompt:
Many websites ask for phone numbers. The problem is that there are so many
different ways to represent a phone number. Examples include 817-555-1234,
817 555 1234 (c), and (817) 555-1234 x23. Write a C++ program which inputs
a string containing a phone number in any format and outputs it in the standard
format. For this assignment, the standard format is (817)555-1234.
Your c++ program should:
1. Input a string including the number
2. Copy only the digits from the input string into another string
3. Issue an error message if the input string does not contain exactly 10
digits
4. Output the phone number in standard format

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_LENGTH = 10;

string ReadAndValidateUserNumber(string userNumber);

int main()
{
    string userNumber;

    ReadAndValidateUserNumber(userNumber);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

string ReadAndValidateUserNumber(string userNumber)
{
    bool check = false;

    while (!check)
    {
        check = true;

        cout << "Please enter a Number: ";
        cin >> userNumber;

        if (userNumber.length() != NUM_LENGTH)
            cout << "The phone number may contain 10 digits only. \n";

        else
        {
            userNumber.insert(0, "(");
            userNumber.insert(4, ")");
            userNumber.insert(8, "-");

            for (int i = 0; i < userNumber.length(); i++)
            {
                if (isdigit(userNumber[i]))
                {
                    userNumber = NUM_LENGTH;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!check)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Entry! Please try again." << endl;
        }
    }

    return userNumber;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What is correct behavior? Examples of bad output? Be specific. This is not a place to ask people to write code for you.

Comment: I apologize. For example if i enter just 10 digits "1123456789", it just says press any key to continue. If i enter something like "123-456-9999", it says error there must be 10 digits only.

Comment: I want the program to spit out the number in the format of (123) 456-9999. I just cant figure out how, and also how to use "isdigit" to extract just the numbers from the string and ignore any letters.

Comment: It is incorrect to apply the ten digit limit to the raw user input. Only after parsing the string and extracting all digits can you validate that digit count. So ditch the check against the string length.

Comment: @Incomputable if he adds the parenthesis or dashes between digit groups he takes the entire string length beyond 10 characters and triggers the error message.

Comment: @MikelF, thanks. Overlooked that

Comment: @Incomputable Easy to do... I only noticed it because of his comment above where he mentioned getting the error message when he entered something that should have been valid.

Comment: bmoney the best thing you can do right now is work through the steps you need to perform on paper. Eg. 1. Take in a string. 2. Remove everything that is not a digit from the string. 3. Verify that you have enough digits remaining in the string. 4. Assemble correct output. Write each of those steps one at a time. Do not proceed to the next step until you have tested the current step and have verified that it works. If step 1 provides bad input to step two, you can't expect step two to work.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a logic error.

```
bool check = false;

while (!check)
{
  check = true;

  ....

  if (!check)
  {
        cout << "Invalid Entry! Please try again." << endl;
  }
}
```

You'll note check never becomes false again. Hence the bottom if statement will never execute and the loop will never iterate more than once as check is always true. You probably want to make

```
check = true
```

conditional on the correct format being entered.

Answer (score 0):

The code is in a horrible state. Calm down and focus. There are many problems aside from what you've written. I recommend you to carry the working code to any code reviewing site.

You're doing the check incorrectly, as well as what you're doing after the check is wrong as well.

```
    userNumber = NUM_LENGTH;
```

This will truncate `NUM_LENGTH` into char, so you'll have something strange inside `userNumber`.

This is the right check:

```
            if (!isdigit(userNumber[i]))
            {
                std::cout << "input should be only numbers\n";
                return; //function should return void
            }
```

^^ this is what you should do if you want to break on non number input, if you want to skip non digits, you can use `std::copy_if` into another string, or tweak the above thing to do it for you. You can also use `std::remove_if` if you want to remove the non number stuff.

```
std::string fetched_input;
std::copy_if(userNumber.begin(), userNumber.end(), fetched_input.begin(), std::isdigit);
```

^^ this will give you the string only with numbers.

Also, you're not doing the check in the correct place. Think about it again.